# How to work with two projects in Netbeans that depend on each other

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I have two projects:

main_project - it was written in Eclipse, it have all backend

gui_project - I'm making front end in Swing for main_project (in Netbeans)

Both have maven pom:

main_project:

```
<groupId>com.group</groupId>
<artifactId>main_project</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>MainProject</name>
```

gui_project:

```
<groupId>com.group</groupId>
<artifactId>gui_project</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>GUI</name>
```

Now I'm trying to use classes from **main_project** in **gui_project** (both are in Netbeans workspace), but I cant make gui_project to see main_project.

Also I added dependency in gui_project:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>main_project</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

**SOLVED**

**Clean and Build** helped (right mouse button on project > clean and build).

Thanks to assylias

Comment: Have you tried adding it as a dependency?

Comment: Have you installed main project (goal: `clean install`)?

Comment: You can add your answer as an answer instead of an edit to your question, so that people know that your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

**Clean and Build** helped (right mouse button on project > clean and build).

Thanks to assylias

Answer (score 0):

the IDE itself should know the link between project right away, meaning no errors in java code in the gui-project. However on the maven side of things, maven's own rules apply. Meaning if 2 projects are not build in the same reactor build (eg. by building a pom project containing both projects as  references) need to be represented by artifact in local repository. So either built upfront or downloaded from a remote (snapshot) repository.